# Quick way to fetch URL html contents with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm not interested in the  QNetWork class and all it's callbacks, I want a static function or something where I can just:

```
QString html = QHttpHelperThingy::fetch("http://blah.com");
```

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is the replacement path: http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html, but QHttp will work throughout 4.x series.

Comment: Yes, with QNetworkAccessManager you can do it in 3 or 4 lines and one slot for the finished() signal.

Do not use QHttp.

Answer (score 1):

[QHttp](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qhttp.html) exists and approximately works as you expect it to, but it's been declared obsolete. I have not found any replacement for it so far.

Comment: +1, I don't find any replacement either, and QnetworkAccessManager does not provide the same level of control